# Can't get to BIOS after first boot of new build

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, desktop-computer, compatibility

Not long ago I decided to make my first build for a desktop and ordered these components:

- mobo: Asus Prime X570-P ATX
- graphics card: MSI GeForce RTX 2070 Ventus 8G
- SSD: M.2 2280 Western Digital Blue SN550 1TB 3D NAND NVMe
- case: ATX Box MSI MAG Forge 100M Black
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 processor 3700X 8-Core (3.6GHz-4.4GHz) 36MB AM4
- RAM: Team Group Kit 32GB (2 x 16GB) DDR4 3200MHz Dark Z Red CL16
- PSU: BitFenix Formula 650W 80+ Gold font

After assembling the components in the box and reviewing the connections several times according to the manuals of the various components, I can't even reach the BIOS settings page, and I get stuck on the motherboard manufacturer's splash screen with the message: `Please press DEL or F2 to enter UEFI BIOS setting`.

[image]

I also have a keyboard connected to the USB input and I tried to click on the keys but without success. The keyboard is receiving power from the motherboard and I have already tested it with two keyboards that work on other machines. I have already reviewed all the connections on the motherboard, I have removed the connections from unnecessary LEDs, I have removed and put all the components and I have tried to connect the machine with just one RAM stick and even in the slots contrary to those indicated in the motherboard manual. I also didn't see any LEDs on the motherboard that indicate a component malfunction. I also checked that all the fans for the various components are operational. Only when I removed the two RAM sticks did the monitor not receive an image and the printer started to ventilate with more power.

Finally, I remembered to look on the ASUS and TeamGroup website if there would be compatibility between the motherboard and the RAM. However, I noticed that the name of the RAMs is not on the list of compatible RAM that was updated on 07/23/2019. I really need your help to understand if it is a compatibility problem between the RAM sticks and the motherboard that I ordered or if it could be from another component. If the compatibility problem is not verified I would like you to help me understand what the problem with my build may be, if possible. This is my first build, I spent 1500 Euros in total with the various components + monitor, and I'm not even getting to the BIOS.

Comment: So I am guessing you have no operating system installed?

Comment: Is the NVMe SSD connected in the slot on the board? If Yes, remove the same and retry. Also there are 2 Pins on the board to reset the BIOS (CMOS) settings (Refer manual it may be terms as CLRTC). Try shorting the 2 pins for 5 -10 seconds (When PC is completely Off) and retry. It will possibly reset the BIOS values to lower defaults and BIOS will retry to set it up again upon next boot. See if it works this time after resetting CMOS.

Comment: No OS installed and I didn't try to reset the BIOS settings because it's the first time I'm booting the machine. The nvme SSD is connected to the m2 slot 1 and I already remove it and retried with no success. Maybe the sad is not compatible with the board?

Comment: Right now SSD compatibility is out of equation because despite removing it, you still get the freeze. I understand this is first boot so ideally CMOS reset should not matter, but still just give it a try. While you have already tried with one RAM, did you try both sticks one by one (one at a time) in each and every slot? Also just try press & hold  Power Button for 30 - 35 seconds when mains is completely off and power chord removed, just to remove any static or residual charges if ever built up.

Comment: The ASUS PRIME X570-P AM4 ATX Motherboard is built on the AMD X570 chipset supporting second- and third-generation AMD Ryzen processors with an AM4 socket. It has four memory slots for up to 128GB of dual-channel DDR4 RAM, which can reach up to 4400 MHz when overclocked.